# Eigen: Compare two sparse matrix with probably different sparsity pattern

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

I want to compare two `Eigen::SparseMatrix`

There are exists `res.isApprox(ans)` method but unfortunately it fail with assertion in case of different sparsity pattern, as far as i know

```
AffineInvariantDeformerTest01: Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrix.h:934: void Eigen::internal::set_from_triplets(const InputIterator&, const InputIterator&, SparseMatrixType&, DupFunctor) [with InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Eigen::Triplet<double, int>*, std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double, int>, std::allocator<Eigen::Triplet<double, int> > > >; SparseMatrixType = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 0, int>; DupFunctor = Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>]: Assertion `it->row()>=0 && it->row()<mat.rows() && it->col()>=0 && it->col()<mat.cols()' failed.
```

I want it for unit tests so it's ok if it will be not so fast. Probably i can transform my sparse matrices to dense, but i hope that there are exist more elegant solution

EDIT:
Just a method which can compare sparsity patterns of two matrices is ok for me too

Comment: If the sparsity-pattern is different, should it return `false`, or should it still be `true`, if structurally different entries are exactly/close to zero?

Comment: @chtz Thank you for comment! For my problem, different pattern means different matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `isApprox()` works fine, even with different sparsity patterns. It looks like your error is elsewhere (likely already when you set your matrix using `setFromTriplets()`)

When given two matrices with different sparsity patterns they will be considered approximately equal, if the differing entries are (almost) zero. The following should calculate `true` twice (increase the `1e-19` to see a difference):

```
#include <Eigen/SparseCore>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> Mat1(2,2), Mat2(2,2);

    std::array<Eigen::Triplet<double,int>, 2> data1  {{{0,0,1.0}, {1,1, 1e-19}}};
    std::array<Eigen::Triplet<double,int>, 2> data2  {{{0,0,1.0}, {1,0, 1e-19}}};

    Mat1.setFromTriplets(data1.begin(), data1.end());
    Mat2.setFromTriplets(data2.begin(), data2.end());

    std::cout << "Mat1.isApprox(Mat1) == " << Mat1.isApprox(Mat1) << "\nMat1.isApprox(Mat2) == " << Mat1.isApprox(Mat2) << "\n";
}
```

If you want to compare the sparsity patterns, you can check the data starting at the inner and outer index pointers (using a Map for both). The following works if both matrices have the same type and are compressed:

```
template<class Derived>
bool hasSamePattern(Eigen::SparseCompressedBase<Derived> const& A, Eigen::SparseCompressedBase<Derived> const& B)
{
    assert(A.isCompressed() && B.isCompressed());
    if(A.rows() != B.rows() || A.cols() != B.cols() || A.nonZeros() != B.nonZeros())
        return false;
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<typename Derived::StorageIndex, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> IndexVector;
    Eigen::Index outerSize = A.outerSize(), nnz = A.nonZeros();
    if(IndexVector::Map(A.outerIndexPtr(), outerSize) != IndexVector::Map(B.outerIndexPtr(), outerSize))
        return false;
    if(IndexVector::Map(A.innerIndexPtr(), nnz) != IndexVector::Map(B.innerIndexPtr(), nnz))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```